# Integer constants as strings?

Tags: java, constructor, constants, final

The requirements for this class is as follows:

> Write a class called Elevator that should contain the following member variables:
>
> - currentFloor (int)
> - elevatorState (an int constant, either IDLE, TO_SOURCE, or TO_DESTINATION)
> - request (Request object representing the request being handled or null if the Elevator is idle)
>
> You should also provide for this class the following:
>
> A default constructor that sets `request` to *null*, `elevatorState` to *IDLE*, and `currentFloor` to 1.
>   Accessor and mutator methods for each variable.
>   Final variables to represent IDLE, TO_SOURCE, and TO_DESTINATION.

Heres what I have:

```
public class Elevator {
    private int currentFloor;
    private int elevatorState;
    private Elevator request;

    public Elevator(){
        currentFloor = 1; 
        elevatorState = ; //this is my problem
        request = null;
    }
}
```

Im confused because it says to declare IDLE, TO_Source, and TO_DESTINATION as integer constants but wouldn't they be strings?

Any clarification would be very helpful.

Comment: Their value doesn't matter. It's just a way to distinguish between different states. Basically the same as an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) (which is actually the correct tool here). You could theoretically use any data type, as long as each of the three values can be uniquely identified.

Comment: This sounds like the perfect time to actually use an Enum for your elevator state.

Comment: those aren't strings. they're constants you define elsewhere, e.g. `final int IDLE = 1` or whatever.

Comment: @DrewKennedy it is! but unfortunately schools (and even universities) teach Java in a way that would never survive a professional code review

Comment: this is more of a questions for the person who assigned you this task as their wording is unclear. The could mean an enum as mentioned above, or a constant id for the state. You should ask them to clarify what they want.

Comment: @Dallen *"Final variables to represent ..."* is inconsistent with enums. The wording alludes to enums not yet taught in class, so `static final int` is needed.

Comment: @Andreas ah yes you are correct, the instructions do seem to imply constants like Marc suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what is being asked of is 3 int constants:

```
public static final int IDLE = 0;
public static final int TO_SOURCE = 1;
public static final int TO_DESTINATION = 2;

public Elevator(){
    currentFloor = 1; 
    elevatorState = IDLE; //this is no longer my problem
    request = null;
}
```

However, if you want to be a mister fancy pants and use OOP *properly* (something that may not be taught), you could use an Enum!

```
public enum ElevatorState {
    IDLE, TO_SOURCE, TO_DESTINATION
}
```

Then in your class:

```
public class Elevator {
    private ElevatorState elevatorState;
    private int currentFloor;
    private Elevator request;

    public Elevator() {
        currentFloor = 1;
        elevatorState = ElevatorState.IDLE; //this is no longer my problem
        request = null;
    }
}
```

My Java is a little rusty, but this should be okay to use.

Comment: *"this is no longer my problem"* +1. Actually, +1 for suggesting enums, so does that make it +2?

Comment: @Andreas Makes it 10, because that sounds better and is still 2 in binary. Win win for everyone. :)

Comment: Drew, each enum is an *object*, an guaranteed-unique instance of the enum class. They do have an ordinal position, though.

Comment: @Andreas Gah, in .NET it's an integer under the hood. I'll remove that bit - thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a possible solution to the problem:

```
public class Elevator 
{
    private static final int IDLE = 0;
    private static final int TO_SOURCE = 1;
    private static final int TO_DESTINATION = 2;

    private int currentFloor;
    private int elevatorState;
    private Elevator request;

    public Elevator(){
        currentFloor = 1; 
        elevatorState = IDLE; //this is my problem
        request = null;
    }

    public int getCurrentFloor() {
        return currentFloor;
    }

    public void setCurrentFloor(int currentFloor) {
        this.currentFloor = currentFloor;
    }

    public int getElevatorState() {
        return elevatorState;
    }

    public void setElevatorState(int elevatorState) {
        if( elevatorState == IDLE ) setRequest( null );
        this.elevatorState = elevatorState;
    }

    public Elevator getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(Elevator request) {
        this.request = request;
    }


}
```